# Incompatibility between xltabular and multirow

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx, multirow, xltabular

When I discovered `xltabular` I said “wow, this is a miracle!”: A package that combines `tabularx` and `longtable` and where one can give ratios of cell widths and a global width, and all calculations are done automatically, a dream becomes reality! And it works great, except for one thing: it seems to be incompatible with `multirow`.

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltabular,multirow}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{makecell}
\setcellgapes{2.5pt}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.4644}
\makegapedcells

\begin{center}\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{|
>{\setlength{\hsize}{0.076\hsize}\centering\arraybackslash}X|
>{\setlength{\hsize}{0.129\hsize}\centering\arraybackslash}X|
>{\setlength{\hsize}{0.087\hsize}\centering\arraybackslash}X|
>{\setlength{\hsize}{0.167\hsize}\centering\arraybackslash}X|
>{\setlength{\hsize}{0.14\hsize}\centering\arraybackslash}X|
>{\setlength{\hsize}{0.116\hsize}\centering\arraybackslash}X|
>{\setlength{\hsize}{0.16\hsize}\centering\arraybackslash}X|
>{\setlength{\hsize}{0.125\hsize}\centering\arraybackslash}X|}
\hline 
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{A. bla bla bla
}
&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{B. bla bla bla
}
&C. bla bla bla bla  bla bla bla bla  bla bla bla bla 
&D. bla bla bla bla  bla bla bla bla  bla bla bla bla
&E. bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  bla bla bla bla bla bla 
\\\cline{1-5}F. bla bla bla bla bla bla 
&G. bla bla bla bla bla bla 
&H. bla bla bla bla bla bla 
&I. bla bla bla bla bla bla 
&J. bla bla bla bla bla bla 
&
&
&\\\hline
\end{xltabular}\end{center}
```

which gives

[image]

Naturally I would like to convert cells C, D and E into 2-row cells to use the vertical space of F-J cells. Using the following code:

```
\begin{center}\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{|
>{\setlength{\hsize}{0.076\hsize}\centering\arraybackslash}X|
>{\setlength{\hsize}{0.129\hsize}\centering\arraybackslash}X|
>{\setlength{\hsize}{0.087\hsize}\centering\arraybackslash}X|
>{\setlength{\hsize}{0.167\hsize}\centering\arraybackslash}X|
>{\setlength{\hsize}{0.14\hsize}\centering\arraybackslash}X|
>{\setlength{\hsize}{0.116\hsize}\centering\arraybackslash}X|
>{\setlength{\hsize}{0.16\hsize}\centering\arraybackslash}X|
>{\setlength{\hsize}{0.125\hsize}\centering\arraybackslash}X|}
\hline 
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{A. bla bla bla
}
&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{B. bla bla bla
}
&\multirow{2}{*}{C. bla bla bla bla  bla bla bla bla  bla bla bla bla}
&\multirow{2}{*}{D. bla bla bla bla  bla bla bla bla  bla bla bla bla}
&\multirow{2}{*}{E. bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  bla bla bla bla bla bla }
\\\cline{1-5}F. bla bla bla bla bla bla 
&G. bla bla bla bla bla bla 
&H. bla bla bla bla bla bla 
&I. bla bla bla bla bla bla 
&J. bla bla bla bla bla bla 
&
&
&\\\hline
\end{xltabular}\end{center}
```

I get the (rather disappointing) result:

[image]

Do you know how to achieve the multi-row effect using `xltabular`?

Comment: For fixed width columns, you should use `\multirow{n}{=}{…}`. Also `\multirow{2}` won't  work because you you have to count the *lines*, not the rows, and possibly adjust the value of n (note you can use decimal numbers for fine tuning). Last remark: the values for `\hsize` are wrong: the sum of the coefficients has to be equal to the total number of `X` columns, which means all your coefficients have to be multiplied by 8.

Comment: Thanks Bernard. I used `\multirow{2}{=}` and it worked *but* the first line of the multi-row cells is not aligned with the first line of cells A and B. Is there a way to remedy to that (besides using a strut), does this mean that `makecell` does not work with `multirow`?

Comment: It may just be a feature of the example but if you use X in every column `tabularx` isn't really doing anything useful; it is just taking multiple passes to come to the conclusion you already know. You could simply use `longtable` and set the columns as `p{.3\textwidth}` or whatever widths you need.  `X` is most useful when at least one column is `l` or `c` and set natural width so you want to calculate how to distribute the unknown remaining width to the X columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play withe optional argument of `\multirow to move upwards or downwards the content of the \multirow. Here is a code with the correct values for \hsize. I also reduced the value of \tabcolsep, because the columns widths are  really small. One also may question  having values up to the third decimal digit.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xltabular,multirow}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{makecell}
\setcellgapes{2.5pt}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.4644}
\makegapedcells

\begin{center}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{|
>{\hsize=0.608\hsize\centering\arraybackslash}X|
>{\hsize=1.032\hsize\centering\arraybackslash}X|
>{\hsize=0.696\hsize\centering\arraybackslash}X|
>{\hsize=1.336\hsize\centering\arraybackslash}X|
>{\hsize=1.12\hsize\centering\arraybackslash}X|
>{\hsize=0.928\hsize\centering\arraybackslash}X|
>{\hsize=1.28\hsize\centering\arraybackslash}X|
>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|
}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{A. bla bla bla
}
&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{B. bla bla bla
}
&\multirow{2}{=}[-0.9ex]{C. bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla}
&\multirow{2}{=}[-0.9ex]{D. bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla}
&\multirow{2}{=}[-0.9ex]{E. bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla}
\\\cline{1-5}F. bla bla bla bla bla bla
&G. bla bla bla bla bla bla
&H. bla bla bla bla bla bla
&I. bla bla bla bla bla bla
&J. bla bla bla bla bla bla
&
&
&\\\hline
\end{xltabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You seem to know `xltabular`well, do you know why I'm not able to put an `xltabular`environment inside a `\scalebox` command?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea. Anyway it is not recommended to scale a table, as it leads to inconsistent font sizes and potentially unreadable contents. Further, I can't imagine you can scale something that's designed to break across pages. In my opinion, it's better to play with \tabcolsep and the font sizes (down to \footnotesize, it should remain readable), or to redesign the whole table, with tricks like swapping rows and columns, put inner titles in the table with \multicolumn, &c. Follow you imagination!

Comment: @yannis it's a longtable so a multi-page vertical mode construct, you can't put it in `\scalebox` because that's `\hbox` more or less.